# Exclude a file from compilation in Eclipse / Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, svn, flash-builder

I'm pulling in an external ActionScript library into my own library.  The external library (as3-commons) has a bunch of logging adapters to different backends.  If I were just linking this library into a standard app, there wouldn't be a problem, because if the class isn't referred to, it won't be compiled.

However, if the library is pulled into a SWC, then Flash Builder will include all classes, and hence get linking erros as it tries to compile against adapters I don't have the code for.  I can disable this, but then I have to manually include every class from that point on.

So, in short, is there a way to:

1. Exclude certain files from an external SVN repository form ever being pulled locally?
2. Exclude a file from compilation in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know compc binary allows just to include a library completely or not at all.

As I am the developer of that particular library (as3commons logging) I just prioritized the separation of the core from setups and integrations.